# Spring Boot request body validation not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

Can anyone tell me what I am missing in this code?
Spring Boot 3.2.3 and this dep is in place:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<?> test(@Valid @RequestBody Test test) {

        System.out.println(test);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

```
@Valid
public class Test {

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private String text;

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    public void setText(@Valid @NotNull final String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

I tried a dozen variants with the annotations but it still doesn't work. POST'ing this payload returns 200 OK:

```
{

}
```

or this

```
{
  "test": {
    
  }
}
```

or this

```
{
  "test": {
    "text": null
  }
}
```

Output on console: `null`

Comment: do you see any error in the logs? have you added the exception handler advice to handle the exception rising our of the validation exception?

Comment: No exception and if there would be any validation happening I wouldn't get 200 OK. Also, my System.out.println() is executed.

Comment: Remove `@Validated` from the class that serves a different purpose and isn't needed. Do you **really** only have `spring-boot-starter-validation` or did you add some `validation-api` dependency yourself as well? Make sure that the annotations you use are from the `jakarta.validation` package and not `javax.validation` as that isn't supported on Spring Boot 3.x anymore.

Comment: Yes, I've read that hint in some other stackoverflow answer as well and removed it. But it still doesn't work. I guess since there is no obvious flaw in my setup I need to dig deeper. I'm usually coding Kotlin on that project and my code is just a Java example in that setup. Maybe I could check that again.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite Test class as below.

```java
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;

public class Test {

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2, message = "should have at least 2 characters")
    private String text;

    public Test() {
    }

    public Test(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

Then to customize the validation response can do as below.

```java
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ValidationHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, WebRequest request) {
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) -> {

            String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
            String message = error.getDefaultMessage();
            errors.put(fieldName, message);
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Tested with these inputs:

```json
{
}

{
    "text":null
}

{
    "text":""
}
```

Response

```json
{
    "text": "must not be empty"
}
```